# g++ throw error without returning value

Tags: c++, function, return, g++, throw

if I have a function with some return value. And I want to throw a exception based on the parameter, is it possible to not write the return value?

For example:

```
State &States::getState(StateType stateType)
{
    for(auto &pair : states)
        if(pair.first == stateType)
            return *pair.second;

    THROW("Cannot find the requested State."); //MACRO TO THROW AND PRINT
}
```

I always get the warning: "control may reach end of non-void function".
How can I remove that warning with only changing my c++ code?

Comment: what about adding a `return` after the `throw` ?

Comment: Yes, that is my question, can I leave the return away? Because this macro basically calls a functions that throws something anyway and there is no point in returning something either, because the state was not found, what can I return?

Comment: I Could return something like `*states.begin().second` but that would have no meaning anyway, because this return point would never be reached anyway.

Comment: @user463035818 What can one return, when the return type is `State&`? There is no _default_ value for a reference.

Comment: Declare the called function as [`[[noreturn]]`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes#Standard_attributes).

Comment: can you do it? of course you can. it is just a warning not an error, though you should actually treat warnings as errors

Comment: Thank you Quentin, but if I do that, I get the warning "function 'getState' declared 'noreturn' should not return", because I return something at `return *pair.second;`. It basically only changed the warning to something else.

Comment: user463035818, Yes thats true, thats why I dont want to have any warning in my project.

Comment: Declare whatever the `THROW` macro calls `[[noreturn]]`, not `getState`.

Comment: Thank you ryhp, that was my mistake.

Comment: What about returning std::optional< State & >?

Comment: Don't write macros that pretend to be functions. Just write a function (or function template) that does what you want it to.

Comment: Btw, this is `return states.at(stateType);` with a different exception text

Comment: @Caleth, yes but I would have to pass __FILE__, __LINE__ and so on for the extra parameters by myself. With macros I do not have to do that.

Answer (score -1):

> is it possible to not write the return value?

For readability purposes, it is always best to specify a return when the function prototype declares it. Steve McConnell writes *"it's harder to understand a routine when, reading it from the bottom, you're unaware of the possibility that it returned somewhere above."*(Code Complete, 393)

> How can I remove that warning with only changing my c++ code?

How about providing a reference parameter to "return" as a workaround? You will need to check if your State class must overload the operator=, however.

```
void States::getState(const StateType stateType, State& toGet)
{
    for(auto &pair : states)
        if(pair.first == stateType)
            toGet = pair.second;

    THROW("Cannot find the requested State."); //MACRO TO THROW AND PRINT
}
```

Comment: You can't declare an uninitialized reference `State& tmpState`

Comment: You can't rebind a reference `tmpState = *pair.second`. `false == bTmp` is normally `!bTmp`. Introducing variables to remove returns isn't great. "Be careful with returning local variables (auto &pair) as references." is just a nonsense. Returning a local reference is fine. Returning a reference to a local, which is what you are trying to do (after the throw, so unreachable), is what you should avoid